# Error "value of key _fn0 is None" during data ingest

Tags: python, mlops, feature-store, mlrun

I got this mistake in MLRun, during ingest values to the FeatureSet:

```
> 2023-05-20 13:11:40,669 [info] loaded project my-project7xx from ./ and saved in MLRun DB
> 2023-05-20 13:11:53,640 [error] For {'_1': 374, '_2': 886, '_3': 989, '_4': 191, '_5': 49, '_6': 658, '_7': 994, '_8': 857, '_9': 217, '_10': 220} value of key _fn0 is None
> 2023-05-20 13:11:53,640 [error] For {'_1': 642, '_2': 688, '_3': 438, '_4': 599, '_5': 176, '_6': 562, '_7': 708, '_8': 444, '_9': 525, '_10': 54} value of key _fn0 is None
```

When I call this part of code:

```
import mlrun
import mlrun.feature_store as fs
...
project = mlrun.get_or_create_project(project_name, context='./', user_project=False)
feature_set = fstore.FeatureSet(feature_name, entities=[fstore.Entity("_fn0",
      value_type=mlrun.data_types.data_types.ValueType.INT32,
      description='fn0 description'),
  fstore.Entity("_fn1",
      value_type=mlrun.data_types.data_types.ValueType.INT32,
      description='fn1 description')],
  engine="storey")
feature_set.save()
...
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=1000,
                                                size=(100, 10)),  # rows, columns
                           columns=[f"_fn{i}" for i in range(10)])
fs.ingest(feature_set, df)
```

Do you know, how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the name of entity, you cannot use prefix `_`. You have to keep limits for definition of name entites/features in FeatureSet. See the [link](https://docs.mlrun.org/en/latest/data-prep/ingest-data-fs.html?ingest-data-using-the-feature-store) to original documentation. You can see here:

- Do not name columns starting with either **_** or **aggr_**. They are
  reserved for internal use. See also general limitations in Attribute
  name restrictions.
- Do not name columns to match the regex pattern
  **.**[a-z]+*[0-9]+[smhd]$**, where **[a-z]+** is an aggregation name, one of:
  **count, sum, sqr, max, min, first, last, avg, stdvar, stddev**. E.g.
  x_count_1h.
- etc.